# C# - Merge Text with Image

Tags: c#, image, text, merge

I wrote the following code for merging 2 images.  My needs were simple, the images will always be the same size so no positioning was needed.  I can deal with that later...  What I am wondering is, can I modify this to merge text label as my imgFront onto an image, imgBack.  The results returned at the end would be a new image that has my text on top.

Is this possible?  How?

```
public static byte[] ImageMerge(Image imgBack, Image imgFront, Int32 width = 200, Int32 height = 200)
{
    using (imgBack)
    {
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                canvas.DrawImage(imgBack, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                canvas.DrawImage(imgFront, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                canvas.Save();
            }
            try
            {
                return ImageToByte(bitmap);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course you can paint text using DrawString(), what doesn't work? (but maybe I didn't understand your question)

Comment: Thanks Adriano!  That's exactly what I was looking for!  (I swear I looked through the Intellisense list and did not see that....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the completed code.  I can't believe I didn't share sooner!

```
public static byte[] ImageTextMerge(Image imgBack, string str, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 w, Int32 h, Int32 width = 200, Int32 height = 200)
{
    using (imgBack)
    {
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                canvas.DrawImage(imgBack, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                // Create font and brush
                Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 20);
                SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

                // Create rectangle for drawing. 
                RectangleF drawRect = new RectangleF(x, y, w, h);

                // Draw rectangle to screen.
                Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Transparent);
                canvas.DrawRectangle(blackPen, x, y, w, h);

                // Set format of string.
                StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
                drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

                // Draw string to screen.
                canvas.DrawString(str, drawFont, drawBrush, drawRect, drawFormat);
                canvas.Save();
            }
            try
            {
                return ImageToByte(bitmap);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```